# Property 'X' does not exist on type 'ParentClass'

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, oop, inheritance

I have multiple classes extending a parent class below:

```
class BaseModel
{
    property = 'random'
}

class ModelA extends BaseModel
{
    methodA() {}
}

class ModelB extends BaseModel
{
    methodB() {}
}
```

I then wrap the models in a decorator which has a property `model` that can store any model. Since they all extend the base class BaseModel, I used that as the type.

```
class Decorator
{
    model: BaseModel

    constructor(model: BaseModel)
    {
        this.model = model;
    }

    // ...decorator methods go here
}

const modelContainerA: Decorator = new Decorator(new ModelA);
const modelContainerB: Decorator = new Decorator(new ModelB);
```

Whenever I run `modelContainerB.model.methodB()`, the code compiles and executes correctly but Typescript throws the following error in my terminal

```
Property 'methodB' does not exist on type 'BaseModel'.
```

After some research I was able to use type assertion to fix it below:

```
(modelContainerB.model as ModelB).methodB()
```

But I don't want to perform a type assertion every single time I access the model. Typescript correctly allowed me to assign a ModelB value to a BaseModel variable since the latter extends the former but it's not able to infer the properties from ModelB. How do I fix that?

Comment: Why would you say `val` is `BaseModel` when you **don't** expect it to be `BaseModel` but `ModelB`?

Comment: If `BaseModel` does not have any properties, it does not really have a reason to exist.

Comment: [^^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76939655/property-x-does-not-exist-on-type-parentclass#comment135634323_76939655) the simple, clean solution in the code shown above is to just remove the type annotation entirely and let TypeScript infer `ModelB`. In situations where you wouldn't want to do that, you can use a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates). There are lots of questions about narrowing with type predicates already here, with answers.

Comment: "*This compiles [...] as expected*" ... Doubt that. If you tell the compiler, that `val` is of type `BaseModel`, the compiler expects `val` to be of type `BaseModel` and thus not having `methodB`.

Comment: @VLAZ because I have multiple Models and I don't want to list each of them as a type when they all extend the same class

Comment: @crazy_abdul that doesn't actually answer my question. Is `val` supposed to be ***all*** subclasses? If so, then your setup is completely off. If it's supposed to be just `ModelB` then again it's wrong. I don't see any reason in this code coupled with your explanation.

Comment: @Pointy BaseModel has properties but I removed to keep the question length fairly short

Comment: @VLAZ in the example, I am assigning ModelB to val but for my use case, it can be any of the classes as I mentioned in the question. Think of this way, I want to able able to assign ModelA ... ModelZ to val without having to specify all the classes in the type like `val: ModelA | ModelB | ModelC` etc.

Comment: @crazy_abdul the thing is, when stuff gets cumbersome and messy with your type architecture, it may be a sign that you need to re-think everything.

Comment: @crazy_abdul In that case, you ***cannot*** expect `methodB()` to be present. If you want to be able to assign all, then what you need is for all to fulfil the correct interface. Thus the method(s) you want to exist should be implemented in each child or in the parent.

Comment: @VLAZ Based on the questions and feedback I have received so far, I have edited the question in hopes that it's clearer what I'm trying to solve. I am not always going to call methodB. the method I call depends on which model is assigned to `val`. I expected TS to infer the properties from the value but it only sees the properties in BaseModel

Comment: It's very clear what you're trying to sole. You seek to fit a square peg in a round hole. That's not proper OOP. If you need the correct method to be called, then you need different implementation in each child, then you assign whatever subclass needs to be and call the method defined in the common interface. That's polymorphism. You are trying to manually reinvent it.

Comment: The proper way to do this, is to make `BaseModel` an `abstract class` with some `method()` and each of the classes inheriting from `BaseModel` implementing this `method` in a way suited for that class ...

Comment: @VLAZ @derpirscher The approach you describe works for actions they share with each other. There are times when I need to access methods unique to each of them. And I want to be able to access that method without typescript showing that error. The JS engine is able to execute the code by the way so that's not the issue. I want a way to tell TS that even though the type of `val` is BaseModel, the value is of type ModelB and it has a method called methodB so there's no need for the error

Comment: If you need specific subtypes, then your OOP approach is wrong.

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks for the suggestions and feedback. Changing the approach might be more work than it's worth at the moment so I'll do consider it as a last resort.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It appears type predicates only work with type guards. The link you shared however covers type narrowing in detail, and I realised the reason for the error is that type narrowing via assignments only works well with union types eg. `ModelA | ModelB` but not class types like `BaseModel`. Using the former, TS correctly knew `val` had access to `methodB` but it couldn't make the right inference when I used `BaseModel`. for now, I might be stuck with type assertions (`(val as ModelB).methodB`) as described in the question until I can find a better solution.

Comment: @crazy_abdul - Yes, type predicates are designed for use in type guards. There's no point in `val` being of type `BaseModel` if you know that it will always be a `ModelB`; it *could* make sense if you have a branch you take **if** its a `ModelB`.  I don't know what you mean about narrowing via assignment, but to be clear type predicates and narrowing are not limited to union types. [Here's an example](https://tsplay.dev/NDAD6m).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You are right. If I was using a global variable `val` I could just set the type to ModelB and avoid all these issues. The actual code, however, doesn't use a global variable. Perhaps I may have oversimplified the code snippets. val is actually a class variable so there isn't much flexibility to set the type when I need it. I have updated the question to reflect this and added as much detail as I can. Hopefully, the question is not too lengthy as a result of this

Comment: @T.J.Crowder About my earlier statement, "narrowing via assignment", I was referring to [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#assignments). They explain how using union types for example (not exclusively) allows TS to know the variable  type based on what you assign to it. This doesn't work with class types which is why I've had to manually assert the type using `modelContainerB.model as ModelB`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for the feedback. Turns out including the decorator code snippet was quite useful after all. Bergi posted an answer that is exactly what I was looking for - generics. Read it in the docs but didn't make the connection. Thanks to everyone for the assistance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html):

```
class Decorator<M extends BaseModel> {
    model: M

    constructor(model: M) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    // ...decorator methods go here
}
```